# How to use java library not supplied as a jar

Tags: java

I am programming a YouTube-Downloader, and I'd like to use the 2 libraries [VGet](https://github.com/axet/vget) and [WGet](https://github.com/axet/wget), since no other library worked. How do I embed those into my project? I'm using IntelliJ 14.

Comment: Are you using maven in your project?

Comment: Or IVY or GRADLE or ...

Comment: Maven (optionally with Nexus or Jenkins) is a good way to do this - if you are allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted at the bottom on the pages of those two libraries, the libraries are available on Maven Central. 
You could search on Maven for "com.github.axet", e.g. http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.axet

Then you'll see the vget and wget libraries. By clicking on the latest version, you come to a page where there is also a jar-file to be downloaded.

But please be aware: Both libraries require additional libraries (e.g. some of the Apache commons libs), which you'll need as well. It is thus highly recommended, to use a dependency management tool like Maven, Ivy or Gradle for your project. I don't know IntelliJ that good, but at least Maven should be supported out of the box. Then all you have to do is specify that you want to use wget and vget, and libraries used by wget or vget will be automatically added to your classpath as well.